# go to another project with different target Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, appdelegate, workspace

i have two project in Xcode  workspace.
let call them project A and project B
in some part of  project A  i want to load  whole  project B

i used this code in appropriate place  of project A  to call secondappdelegate of project B FOR load second project:

```
#import “SecondAppDelegate.h"

//and use


_appDelegate =( SecondAppDelegate* )[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;


_mainTabsController = [[TGMainTabsController alloc] initWithPresentation:_presentation];
        [_mainTabsController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:_contactsController, _callsController, _dialogListController,_appDelegate ,_accountSettingsController, nil]];
```

but  _appDelegate  is nil and application crash

Comment: Goto this [link](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=how+to+load+one+project+into+other+xcode&oq=how+to+load+one+project+into+other+xcode&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.9551j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), and try everything

Comment: @dahiya_boy It's usually much better to provide a duplicate question or a direct blog post/article instead of a link to Google.